# facebook like button not showing in Mozilla but working fine in chrome & safari

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have site where i used addthis sahring icons code to display the scocial sharing icons. Fb like button is not coming in mozilla but it is working fine in chrome & safari.

I used the below code for displaying the sharing icons as get from addthis site https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing?frm=hp#.UDrCVsHib-s

```
   <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
   <div id="fb-root"></div><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like"     fb:like:layout="button_count" ></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_tweet"   ></a>
   <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"  ></a>
   <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"  ></a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-5022bfc615892c77"></script>
```

Comment: Sometimes plugins can cause this.  Do you have adblock or something similar installed on Firefox?

Comment: In the site, i used fb like other places also. It is working there. Only issuw with this addthis fb like

Comment: site url is http://www.inspiretheentrepreneur.com/2012/06/28/zappos-drop-shipping-business-success-story/

Comment: I can see the like button fine.  I'm in firefox 14 on linux.

Comment: I am checking in windows ff 14

Comment: i just noticed that problem is in chrome also, sometime fb like  is coming or sometime not

Comment: Surely there is js error on this page

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code for sharing on Facebook, i have use this tons of time and each time i get success, change the sequence if you want...

```
<span class='st_fblike_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_email_vcount'></span>
<span class='st_sharethis_vcount'></span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "782110c4-838d-408f-8393-98897995ced4"}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp-content/plugins/facebook-like-box-responsive/facebook-like-responsive.css

e.g http://blogs.tarungupta.info/wp-content/plugins/facebook-like-box-responsive/facebook-like-responsive.css

remove !important

```
/* To fill the container and nothing else */
.fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget span, .fb_iframe_widget span iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

/* To fill the container and nothing else */
.fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget span, .fb_iframe_widget span iframe {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```